# Can I only return an anyonymous class with Json?

Tags: c#, json

I have the following code:

```
            return Json(new {
                ent = vm.ent,
                errors = e.Message,
                fld = vm.fld,
                pk = vm.pk,
                success = false,
                rk = vm.rk,
                _rk = _rk,
                val = vm.val
            });
```

The code works but I am wondering if I can do this with a class instead of an anonyomous array. It just seems that with the anonymous way there is no checking for the field names.

Comment: What do you mean about 'no checking for the field names' that array of anonymous objects should have the same properties? What Json do you want to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return whatever class you want. I have not tested it but it would not make sense to only work with anonymous class. More to the point it seems the easies thing to try if you have a project running.

I don't know what exactly you mean by "checking for field names" but you can use anonymous classes like this:

```
new { vm.val, vm.pk }
```

In this case the property of the anonymous class takes the name of the property that was assigned.

P.S. you are breaking all .NET conventions by using lowecase names for public members.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about conventions. I don't usually use lowercase and will fix that right away. What I mean is that my javascript that receives the json expects names such as pk, rk. With an anonymous class on the C# side there is no error checking. I could easily code that up using pkx and rkx. I could create the anonymous class and it would not get checked until run time.

Comment: You can't do compile time checks on C# code that will be sent to JS anyway. After all the code is written in different languages and executed on different computers.